# Program deleting file of other user - permission denied

Tags: c++, linux, file

I have two Users. User1 is running a program which tries to delete a file from user2. But my program always return me "permission denied".

When I try to delete the file myself as user1 with the rm command there is no problem. The permission of the files are 775 and my user1 is in the group of user2. This group is also the owner of the files. The permission of the directory in which the files are is 775 too.

For removing the file the program I have written uses the "remove" function from c/c++.
Does anyone have a solution or idea ?

I have asked this question on unix.stackexchange.com before. They have sent me here.

Here is my code:

```
    void deleteFile()
{

    if(0 != remove("File1.txt"))
        cout<<"Error deleting File: "<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
    if(0 != remove("File2.txt"))
        cout<<"Error deleting File: "<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
}
```

i have renamed the files but i know the original paths are correct. i have already tested this

more information:
ok i have runnned the program as user2 and the files have been deleted without any problems.

`groups user1
users user2`

`groups user2
user2 adm www-data plugdev users ftp vsftpd`

`ls -lah
drwxrwxr-x 7 user2 user2 4.0K Nov 27 14:13 .
drwxrw-r-x 4 user2 user2 4.0K Nov 11 12:34 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user2 user2 50  Nov 12 15:12 File1.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user2 user2 826 Nov 27 14:13 File2.txt`

Comment: Post you code to get more help

Comment: Check your assumptions on the actual permissions. Show the output of `ls -l`. The actual permissions from the actual output. This isn't a programming error (aside from not setting `errno = 0` before you call `remove()`), but a permission issue.

Comment: i have checked again an like i said the files have the permission 775. 
also the parent directory has 775.
An if i try to remove the file myself (logged in as user1) i can remove them without any problems with "rm File1.txt" .
The permissions should be set correct instead i could not do this. The problem is that the program can't remove the files :/

Comment: Please update your question to show the output of `ls -Al` so we can see the permissions on the directory.

Comment: ok i have update again

Answer (score 0):

I did a test, below, which demonstrates that to delete a file, a user needs to have write permission for the directory which contains the file.  According to your output from "ls -l" your user2 should be permitted to delete (remove) the file.

Your code example does not compile.  Can you provide a complete code example that demonstrates your problem?  The simple program below behaves as expected.  You might try your test with this simpler example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
{

    printf("result: %i\n", remove("/home/user1/delete_me"));
}
```

I think your problem is not related to file permissions.

```
newf:~# groups user1
user1 : user1
newf:~# groups user2
user2 : user2 user1
newf:~# su - user1
$ date > delete_me
$ chmod g+w delete_me
$ exit
newf:~# su - user2
$ ls -la ~user1
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Nov 28 13:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root  root  4096 Nov 28 13:19 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   29 Nov 28 13:28 delete_me
$ date >> ~user1/delete_me
$ cat ~user1/delete_me
Fri Nov 28 13:28:44 EST 2014
Fri Nov 28 13:31:39 EST 2014
$ rm ~user1/delete_me
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/user1/delete_me’: Permission denied
$ exit
newf:~# su - user1
$ chmod g+w .
$ exit
newf:~# su - user2
$ ls -la ~user1 
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Nov 28 13:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root  root  4096 Nov 28 13:19 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   58 Nov 28 13:31 delete_me
$ rm ~user1/delete_me
$ ls -la ~user1
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 user1 user1 4096 Nov 28 13:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root  root  4096 Nov 28 13:19 ..
```

Comment: i have already written in my question that the user can remove the files if i do it myself with "rm" . But if the user runs the program wich tries to delete the file i get back the error saying permission denied

Answer (score -3):

You are not using `remove` correctly. It is simply:

```
remove("File1.txt")
```

instead of

```
remove(("File1.txt").c_str())
```

which when compiling results in the error:

```
error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘("File1.txt")’, which is of non-class type ‘const char [10]’
```

For error checking:

```
if(remove("File1.txt") == -1)
     error occurred
```

Comment: But how would this a) compile, and then b) result in "Permission denied"?

Comment: Did you compile with **Warnings** enabled? (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`)? As to b), I suspect it was trying to delete a malformed filename, but you will have to look at it in a debugger.

Comment: Sorry the c_str() function is because of i am using string and have to convert them for the remove function. I have just forgotten to remove them by cleaning the code for here. Buti have tested your suggest to and still no permission.

Comment: That (edit artifact) is basically what I suspected. If the file wouldn't exist, it wouldn't complain about permissions.

Comment: What are the downvotes for? The answer was 100% correct. Do you have a different `man remove` on your system than I?

Comment: David, the question is about denied permissions. Your answer is about an artifact that happened when scrux dumbed down his code for posting, resulting in an error that doesn't happen with the OP's original code. Good you pointed it out, but that should have been a comment, not an answer, no longer applies, and doesn't help scrux with his problem.

Comment: Then it is either a directory owner/group issue or a uid/euid gid/egid issue. None of that makes corrections to the code incorrect. That is entirely bunk. Maybe my crystal ball was supposed to know the question (as written) was just there by mistake and the artifacts would be removed later?

Comment: Post corrections to example code unrelated to the actual problem as comments. They are not helpful as anwers, not for scrux (except to improve his question, which he did), not for future visitors (at all).

Comment: If the code is wrong, and you post corrections, those corrections are (Not Unhelpful) by definition. No good deed goes unpunished. Happy Thanksgiving.

Comment: Oh geez... Pointing out the artifact is certainly appreciated, **but should have been a comment**. You do realize this is not an answer to the question as it stands, let alone a helpful one? Delete it, and a) the downvotes are gone, b) it doesn't distract others from actually answering the question.

Comment: `remove()` is defined to return zero on success, non-zero on failure. Comparing the result to `-1` can miss errors. (Some systems may define `-1` as the error return value, but checking for inequality to `0` is more portable.)

Comment: Downvoting is not about punishment. Answers need to *answer the question*.